# Should use Dagger for unit tests in Android project?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I need clarification regarding using Dagger for unit tests on Android projects because I found two different opinions on the Dagger testing docs and Google Dagger code lab which are opposed to each other.

According to the Unit tests and manual instantiation section of [Dagger testing docs](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/testing):

> It is generally recommended to create a Dagger component in your tests
> to instantiate objects, whether that is a larger test component for
> many tests or a small focused test component for the individual test.

According to the Unit tests section of [Google code lab description](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-dagger#13):

> You don't have to use Dagger-related code for unit tests. When testing
> a class that uses constructor injection, you don't need to use Dagger
> to instantiate that class. You can directly call its constructor
> passing in fake or mock dependencies directly just as you would if
> they weren't annotated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opinions do not conflict: they offer two choices to take depending on complexity.

The Dagger docs link to the [Hilt testing philosophy](https://dagger.dev/hilt/testing-philosophy.html#manual-instantiation) page, which I'll summarize:

- Constructing instances can be difficult in complex and interconnected apps. Dagger was made to solve this problem.
- Unit tests also need to construct instances of the system under test. Doing so manually means ignoring the tool you use to solve the problem in production.
- Managing a separate graph for production  versus unit and integration tests is difficult but doable in raw Dagger, but is meant to be substantially easier in Hilt.
- Manual injection is possible but has downsides:

  - **Over-reliance on mocks** that can go stale, leading to testing assumed (mocked) behavior rather than real behavior. This includes when systems change over time, particularly in how they handle edge cases.
  - **Difficulty recreating scoped objects**: you're signing up to create Provider and Lazy wrappers as Dagger would, and if you get it wrong you might create false positive and false negative results.
  - **Tight coupling between a system and its test**, since refactors that change a constructor will also need to change all of its manual callers.

All that said, Dagger is explicitly designed to allow for explicit constructor calls [as if you had written the factory code explicitly yourself](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/):

> The guiding principle is to generate code that mimics the code that a user might have hand-written to ensure that dependency injection is as simple, traceable and performant as it can be.

This also eases adoption into existing projects: unlike some other possible dependency injection solutions, you can write a class that can be called manually with explicit manual dependency injection, but then Dagger writes the implementations you would have written yourself.

The codelab, which is designed for illustrative usage from beginners, shows both cases: it shows that you can call the constructor yourself in a unit test, with a single mocked scopeless UserManager dependency, but then also shows how to configure an end-to-end test graph. The Dagger site acknowledges this possibility of direct constructor calls but asserts that outside of small toy problems, even unit tests will start to become too complex to warrant manual DI. (Try adding 7 more dependencies to LoginViewModel in the codelab, including a few scopes, then try refactoring it to reorder or remove dependencies. You might see what they mean, or lose some confidence in the completeness and accuracy of your test.) At that point you may want to use a tool like Hilt as it was designed, to ease construction in unit tests as well as integration and production environments.

---

In summary: the Dagger codelab shows a *simple* case and what you *can* do *manually*. The docs describe the eventual likely scaling problems, leading to what (they say) you *should* do *eventually*. There's no problem with letting both styles coexist in a codebase and migrating  tests of large classes gradually as you see the need.